# Database or XML which one is better for Commentary based implementation?

Tags: java, php, xml, database

I have a cricket based website and implemented a commentary 
using the database and php, but i really feel its slow.

So my questions is how is the espncricinfo.com has implemented their commentary section
http://www.espncricinfo.com/the-ashes-2010-11/engine/current/match/446963.html

What is the technology behind this Database or xml files or any other way?

Is database is a right choice to implement this kind of requirement, as there millions of users accessing the system? and few system will keep updating the ongoing cricket match.

Comment: Certainly a better one than flat XML files. Also they probably use some caching mechanism for such content.

Comment: could I ask you to edit your question title to include an upper case L in XML? Looks like XMI otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

Database and XML aren't opposites - this looks an ideal application for an XML database!

But whichever technology you use, you will need to pay careful attention to performance at every stage of implementation. Poor performance is rarely the consequence of choosing technology that isn't up to the job, but it's often the consequence of using technology that you don't understand well enough.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say without knowing the exact specifications of your system, including system resources, number of users etc.

Given that you will have very few update sources and many just viewing the data it would certainly be possible to implement this in XML. Depending on how you've built the auto-refresh function of  the commentary you might already be using XML to send updates back.

I suspect that whichever system you choose the main performance enhancement you could make would be to ensure that data that is frequently accessed is cached in memory and refreshed only when your data storage is updated.